# Bookmarklet that uses current url in post request

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet

Sorry if my question displays a lack of fundamental Javascripting knowledge as I have next to none.

I Frankensteined together the following bookmarklet during hours of obsessive Googling for a way to do what I want to do:

```
javascript:'<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()"><form method="post" action="https://generic.web.proxy/request.php?do=go"><input type="text" name="get" value=???></form>'
```

[(Mostly based on this.)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3791217/5661587)

Basically, it mostly does what it should: performing a post request on that web proxy's page with whatever string is used for `value`. The problem is what I want to use for `value`, namely the URL of the current Firefox tab. In other bookmarklet examples I've seen this seems to be accomplished with `location.href`, but if I do it like this

```
value=location.href
```

it simply assumes that it's the string "location.href". I assume that's because I'm stupidly trying to directly use a Javascript thingie in the html part of the script, but what is the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy, I think I just figured it out. Since the javascript treats the html like any other string, I can simply use normal string manipulation on it:

```
'<beginningofhtml'+location.href+'endofhtml>'
```

Applied to my bookmarklet:

```
javascript:'<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()"><form method="post" action="https://generic.web.proxy/request.php?do=go"><input type="text" name="get" value='+location.href+'></form>'
```

And it works!

(the fake example web proxy url still needs to be replaced with the correct one of corse; it works with a site called Proxfree)